# The direct product of two proper commuting subgroups of a non-abelian indecomposable finite group G can be equal to G?

Tags: finite-groups

Let G be a finite non-abelian indecomposable group. Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be two proper subgroups of $G$. Assume that $G_1$ and $G_2$ commute, i.e., for every $g_1$ in $G_1$ and $g_2$ in $G_2$ we have $g_1 g_2=g_2 g_1$. Is it possible for the "product" of $G_1$ and $G_2$ to be equal to $G$ ? where the "product" of $G_1$ and $G_2$ is the set $\{g_1 g_2: g_1 \in G_1, g_2 \in G_2\}$

Comment: $G$ is indecomposable, so the answer is no (unless $G_1$ or $G_2$ is trivial, which you didn't care to exclude). I'm not really sure whether this is what you intended to ask.

Comment: $G$ is non-trivial. $G_1$ and $G_2$ could have non-trivial intersection. Is you answer still true ? Do you have a proof ? thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: If $G_1$ and $G_2$ generate their direct product, their intersection is trivial by definition. (Also you didn't ask $G_1$ or $G_2$ to be nontrivial.)

Comment: I don't understand your comments. There might be some confusion regarding the terminology. I apologize for any misunderstanding in advance. Let me try to clarify further. When I refer to the direct product of $G_1$ and $G_2$, I mean the set $\{g_1 g_2: g_1 \in G_1, g_2 \in G_2\}$. I do not think I have to say that $G_1$ and $G_2$ are non trivial unless $G$ is trivial...

Comment: So this is not the direct product. You should fix it in the post.

Comment: what is the right name ?

Comment: And yes, "central products" yield groups indecomposable groups $G$ with two commuting proper subgroups $G_1,G_2$ with $G_1G_2=G$. This might be exactly what you're looking for, since $G_1\cap G_2$ is necessarily central in your context, so we always have a quotient of $G_1\times G_2$ by a central subgroup.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151943/discussion-between-luciano-and-ycor).

Comment: Yes, what you've described is exactly a central product of groups. They're often indecomposable. A good finite example to think of is extraspecial groups.

Comment: I can't find an example. Could you please provide one?